# Box-shadows on rotated elements in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a simple 30x30px div that has a box-shadow. The shadow shows up fine, except when using a rotation. With a rotation, the box-shadow dissapears. I can't figure what's causing this. Is it my fault, or a browser bug? A nested div in which the parent is rotated and the child is rotated back works fine.

I am using Firefox 28.0a2 on Windows XP. It does work in Chrome, as far as I can tell.

[image: example image]

[image: Dabblet Demo]

Comment: It works, I'm using Firefox 26.0 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in my machine. If you use Firefox, check the version that supports html5 as well as css3.

Don't forget to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the html page.

You should include the browser-specific styles in your CSS:

```
div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
}
```

Hope this helps!